# out-mode parameters in scheme recursive function

Tags: recursion, scheme, parameter-passing

Reader beware: Clueless about functional programming and even more clueless about Scheme.

I have a recursive function in Scheme.  In the non-base-case portion, the function calls itself twice, comparing the two calls in an if statement.  I need to return the result that is greater. So... what I'm currently doing is:

```
(if (> (recursive-call a b-1) (recursive-call a-1 b))
    (recursive-call a b-1)
    (recursive-call a-1 b))
```

Which obviously requires that I make 3 recursive calls instead of 2.

Is there a way to reference the value of the recursive calls from the if statement?  I am not allowed to define additional functions or use let.  I'm thinking it has to do with out-mode parameters but don't know how to use, assign, or access the value of an out-mode parameter.  When I asked the professor, I was pointed to parameter passing methods in functional languages as well as the general process of a function return.  It wasn't helpful in the least.  I can't post the full code as it's an assignment for a class. Any chance this is enough for someone to point me in the right direction?

Note: The only constructs we're allowed are null?, car, cdr, else, lcm, +, >, if, parameters to the recursive function (which must be a list and numbers only), integer literals, and parenthesis.  No use of max, define, or let, unfortunately.

Comment: Using the built-in `max` procedure, you can do `(max (recursive-call a b-1) (recursive-call a-1 b))` instead of having an if statement. Or, you can define variables whose values will be the recursive calls, then you can compare those variables in an if statement using the setup you already have: `(if (> a b) a b)`, whereby a is the first recursive call `(define a (recursive-call a b-1))` and b the other.

Comment: If you're allowed `lambda`, remember `(let ((x e)) b)` <=> `((lambda (x) b) e)`.

Comment: Again, no lambda, no let.  Only null?, car, cdr, else, lcm, +, >, if, parameters to the recursive function, integer literals, and parenthesis.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post like that.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: `b-1` and `a-1` are names for variables. If you wanted a subtraction you'd use `(- a 1)`. I'll use `(- a 1)` in my answer, but if it really was a variable you can just replace it.*

The obvious way to do this particular logic without restrictions is:

```
;; return the largest of the two
(max (recursive-call a (- b 1)) 
     (recursive-call (- a 1) b))
```

The standard Scheme way would be to bind values you use more than once in variables using `let` so that you don't do the computation more than you need to:

```
;; cache computed values in local bindings
(let ((a (recursive-call a (- b 1)))
      (b (recursive-call (- a 1) b)))
  (if (> a b) a b))
```

Since you are restricted to not use either of those you can rewrite the `let` version to its primitive form. A let can be rewritten like this:

```
(let ((ba va) (bb vb))
  ...)

; ===
((lambda (ba bb)
   ...)
 va
 vb)
```

I guess you should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Deleted comment.

Comment: @MichelleWilliamson Without `lambda` or `define` how are you supposed to make a function to begin with? It's like a running competition that disqualifies everybody with legs.

Comment: define and lambda are used to create the recursive function.  We are not allowed to use them again nor modify the given definition of the function.  The only thing we are allowed to do is add things inside cond. And the things we are allowed to add inside condition can only contain the constructs given.

Comment: @MichelleWilliamson In that case its either ok with redundant calls or you are stuck with an XY problem where your chosen solution is what makes you stuck and that the originally problem can be solved within those restrictions easily. Perhaps if we knew your actual problem and saw what you had so far we might point you in a different direction.

Comment: Thanks @sylwester.  Unfortunately, I can't post any more.  I already feel like I'm right at that line where a professor might take issue if I post anymore.  I did hear back from the professor again though and the solution I have is correct.  His response yesterday sent me on a wild goose chase thinking there had to be a more optimal solution and that I just didn't have the knowledge and experience in the language.